# How to save the results of a function to a text file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the function below that produce multiple outputs, is there a way I can put all the outputs of the function in a text file. I tried below to use Out-File it did not work any suggestions?

```
cls

function functionAD {Write-output ""...}

functionAD | Out-File -FilePath C:\test\task5.txt -Append
```

the script above still did not work.

Comment: Don’t use `write-host` to output anywhere but the console. Use `write-output` instead.

Comment: [1] you need to append the output if you want anything other than the last item to show up. [*grin*] [2] your `it did not work` is ... fabulously inadequate ... to help anyone find out what went wrong.

Comment: still did not work the text file is empty

Comment: @secatt - Post *real code* that does not work. This works: `function functionAD {Write-output "test"};functionAD | Out-File -FilePath $env:temp\task5.txt -Append;gc $env:temp\task5.txt;`

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This is, in fact, possible if you overwrite the `Write-Host` function. It can be done like this:

```
function Write-Host($toWrite) {
    Write-Output $toWrite
}
```

Copy and paste this code into your PowerShell console, then run the program.

Don't worry about permanently overwriting the `Write-Host` command, this will only last for the current session.

> OLD COMMENT:
>
> Unfortunately, `Write-Host` can not be rerouted to another file stream. It is the only 'write' command that acts in that way. That is why PowerShell programmers generally try to avoid using it unless there is a specific reason to. It is intended for messages sent directly to the user and is thus send to the program (powershell) itself rather than a console.
>
> I would suggest using some other command if the function is your own. `Write-Output` is always a safe bet because it can be redirected to any other stream.
>
> Here is a link if you have more questions: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/